# No sound playback during call in Slack - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, slack

I'm on 20.04 and downloaded Slack using snap. I downloaded Spotify via snap as well as my speakers work. Not sure why Slack isn't working. I tried every single sound source.

I have been able to successfully record/playback in Audacity. So that's good.

[image]

[image]

Comment: please give more details e.g.  screenshot of `pavucontrol` playback/output tab , do you use a browser version or installed version ?

Comment: @Benjiover_9000'benchonaut' Sure -- added it in. I am using the application.

Comment: okay, slack recommends to "try the browser version" , there seem to be people able to use it https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/523297/make-slack-prefer-my-headset-for-audio-as-it-used-to , but you are not alone  : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182580/no-sound-in-various-apps-on-19-10

Comment: I think I found a solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1482497/audio-not-working-for-some-applications-ubuntu-20-04-06/1482498 In my case it was a problem related to Chromium and I solved it through pavucontrol.