# Audio not working for some applications - Ubuntu 20.04.06

Tags: sound, alsa, chromium

I have a problem with the system sound in some applications. It won't reproduce any audio on some specific installed apps (for the moment I've experienced this with Slack, which was installed via snap, and Telegram Web-.AppImage version). Other workmates also use Slack with Ubuntu and aren't getting this problem.

The audio is working properly on web browser (Mozilla Firefox), on Spotify and on local video player, which were installed via snap.

It looks similar to these questions, but they didn't get any useful answers:

- [No sound in various apps on 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182580/no-sound-in-various-apps-on-19-10)
- [No sound playback during call in Slack - Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251943/no-sound-playback-during-call-in-slack-ubuntu-20-04)

`sudo lspci -v` output:

```
0000:00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 51c8 (rev 01) (prog-if 80)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0b1a
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 209
    Memory at 6189290000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 6189000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
```

`aplay --list-devices`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC289 Analog [ALC289 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 12: HDMI 6 [HDMI 6]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 13: HDMI 7 [HDMI 7]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 14: HDMI 8 [HDMI 8]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 15: HDMI 9 [HDMI 9]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 16: HDMI 10 [HDMI 10]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 17: HDMI 11 [HDMI 11]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution following these steps.

1. First, install `pavucontrol` via the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

2. Open it running `pavucontrol`.
3. Go to `Playback` and on the `Show` field select `Applications`.
4. Reproduce any multimedia with an audio that wasn't working. `pavucontrol` should show the audio being reproduced, and it should look like:
   [pavucontrol look showing a new Chromium output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogWLC.png)
5. If the Speaker button is at a muted state, click it to unmute it.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: it's not showing the audio from applications which are broken. is there a way to force it to discover more?